# How to set a service account thats in JSON format with firebase functions:config:set

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I dont want to set each part of my service's account config JSON file individually like `js firebase functions:config:set service_account.token="..." service_account.key="service_account.json"`.

I read that I could do this all at once with this command `firebase functions:config:set service_account="$(service_account.json)"`

However the error I'm getting from this is `Invalid argument, each config value must have a 2-part key (e.g. foo.bar).`

When I do add at a second part to the key it adds the string as whole to the config, e.g. `service_account.account = "$(service_account.json)"` is literally the value of the key

When I do `"$(cat service_account.json)"` it throws the error precondition check failed.

Anyone has any idea how can I get to do this?

Comment: You're going to have to encode or escape that token string so that your shell sees it as a single argument.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I think Doug is asking you to change the format of your token string so that it would appear as one part instead of two.